# fill a file inside a inner class

Tags: java, file, twitter4j

I'm quiet new to java and I'm not even sure if the title makes any sense.
Anyway how do I gain access to a file inside of onStatus?
I'm just trying to write into a file in that function so in the code below "T_file.length()" the "T_file" cannot be resolved.

```
public static void main (){
    foo("file_name");
}

foo(String fileName)
{
        try{
        final File T_file = new File (fileName);
        final FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
        final BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);
        }catch (IOException e){}

        StatusListener listener = new StatusListener(){     
        public void onStatus(Status status){
            if (T_file.length() > 100){
                    System.out.println ("I have access here");
                  }
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: First of all, did you import `java.io.File`?

Comment: yes, I imported all I assume is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "T_file.length()" the "T_file" cannot be resolved

This is because `T_file` is not in the scope of `onStatus`. You declare `T_file` in the `foo` method, but then create a new `StatusListener` in which you redefine the `onStatus`, but the compiler still see `StatusListener` as an other class.

A workaround would be to declare the variable `globally` in your class, then access it specifying the name of your `Class.this.T_file`. Here an example :

```
public class Foo {

    File T_file;

    public static void main (){
        new Foo("file_name");
    }

    Foo(String fileName)
    {

        T_file = new File (fileName);        

        StatusListener listener = new StatusListener(){     
            public void onStatus(Status status){
                if (Foo.this.T_file.length() > 100){
                    System.out.println ("I have access here");
                  }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This example would compile.

Notice that I added a `;` at the end of the `StatusListener`, else it would not compile.

Comment: if I make it 'static File T_file' I don't have to use the 'class.this.T_file' is this a valid change? I will be calling the function numerous times and for some reason I can't do 'class.this.T_file'

Comment: @John Yes that would also works. However I don't really understand why you can't do `class.this.T_file` but anyway.